# Как обобщить вызов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Требуется по клику на каждый идентификатор принимать данные с сервера. 
Как можно обобщить это?

```
<th><a id="nameUP">&#9650;</a> Имя <a id="nameDOUN">&#9660;</a></th>
<th><a id="seurnameUP">&#9650;</a> Фамилия <a id="seurnameDOUN">&#9660;</a></th>
<th><a id="mygroupUP">&#9650;</a> Группа <a id="mygroupDOUN">&#9660;</a></th>
<th><a id="ballsUP">&#9650;</a> Баллы <a id="ballsDOUN">&#9660;</a></th>
```

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы возникало событие при нажатии на любую ссылку ?

Comment: Опишите свой вопрос лучше, ибо пока что не понятно, чего вы хотите.

Comment: @Alex Даже не знаю как объяснить. В общем по клику на ссылку происходит событие. А именно я должнен принять массив. Что требуется : не писать каждый раз  nameUP (делай то то ) ballsUP(делай то то ) . Нужно это дело как то упростить

Comment: @ДимаПерильман  **1)** как именно Вы принимаете массив с сервера (ajax?) **2)** адрес для получения массива одинаковый или разный для каждого id **3)** приходит 1 и тот же массив или разный для каждого id ?

Comment: @Alex *1)* ajax-да  *2)* один файл отправляет и один и тот же все принимает и потом формирует таблицу. *3)* разные по задумке. Или лучьше в JS сортировать что бы негонять туда сюда разные большие объемы данных?

Comment: @ДимаПерильман возможно Вам нужно это - https://jsfiddle.net/cykdnzop/1/ ?

Comment: @Alex Да годиться))) Забираю))) Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#nameUP, #seurnameUP, #mygroupUP, #ballsUP").on("click", function() {
  // отпраляете запрос на сервер и получаете данные
  //...
  //действие в зависимости от того, какую ссылку нажали
  if (this.id == 'nameUP') {
    alert('действие для nameUP');
  } else if (this.id == 'seurnameUP') {
    alert('действие для seurnameUP');
  } else if (this.id == 'mygroupUP') {
    alert('действие для mygroupUP');
  } else if (this.id == 'ballsUP') {
    alert('действие для ballsUP');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<th><a id="nameUP">&#9650;</a> Имя <a id="nameDOUN">&#9660;</a></th>
<th><a id="seurnameUP">&#9650;</a> Фамилия <a id="seurnameDOUN">&#9660;</a></th>
<th><a id="mygroupUP">&#9650;</a> Группа <a id="mygroupDOUN">&#9660;</a></th>
<th><a id="ballsUP">&#9650;</a> Баллы <a id="ballsDOUN">&#9660;</a></th>
```